# Routing in Leaflet

Tags: javascript, routes, leaflet, coordinates, geocoding

At the Moment I'm working on a simulation that should generate a route on leaflet an lets an Icon drive along it. The routing is performed via the [Leaflet Routing Machine](http://www.liedman.net/leaflet-routing-machine/). I´m getting the waypoints of the route and update the marker position in an interval. The problem is: A curve has more waypoints than a straight road so the simulated Car slows down in roundabouts and goes VERY fast on straight Highways.

Here is the Code described above. It would be really nice if someone could help me out.

```
        //assigning an object for the start
        // can be looped in further development
        var EO = {
            'lat' : 47.408478097049354, 
            'lng' : 13.215466182754234
        };

        //assigning an object for the destination
        var ZO = {
            'lat' : 47.434806991283295,
            'lng' : 13.25299679959033 
        };

        //assigning an Icon for the car
        var NefIcon = L.icon({
            iconUrl: "{% static '\img\map\icon_vhcle\Car.png' %}",
            iconSize: [99, 50]
        })

        var marker = L.marker([ZO.lat, ZO.lng], { icon: NefIcon }).addTo(map);
        
        
        L.Routing.control({
            //defining the Waypoints
            waypoints: [
                L.latLng(EO.lat, EO.lng ),
                L.latLng(ZO.lat, ZO.lng)
            ],
            //settings
                routeWhileDragging: true,
                draggableWaypoints: false,
                addWaypoints: false
        }).on('routesfound', function (e) {
                var routes = e.routes;
                console.log(routes);

                for (let index = 0; index < e.routes[0].coordinates.length; index++) {
                    
                    
                    setTimeout(function () {
                    var latIcon = e.routes[0].coordinates[index].lat
                    var lngIcon = e.routes[0].coordinates[index].lng
                    console.log(latIcon);
                    marker.setLatLng([ latIcon, lngIcon]);
                    
                },300*index)
                    
                }
                /*e.routes[0].coordinates.forEach(function (coord) {
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        marker.setLatLng([coord.lat, coord.lng]);
                    }, 1000 * index)
                })*/

            }).addTo(map);
```

Comment: https://leafletjs.com/plugins.html#overlay-animations

Comment: Great! Thank you. Works as it should.